# Acumatica Exception retrieving User Field

Tags: acumatica

I have the following code:

```
protected void SOLine_UsrMargin_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e)
{
    var salesOrderEntry = (SOLine)e.Row;
    if (salesOrderEntry == null)
        return;

    decimal? lastCost = GetLastCost(salesOrderEntry.InventoryID);
    decimal margin = (decimal)cache.GetValue<SOLineExt.usrMargin (salesOrderEntry); <-- Line 47
    .
    .
    .
}
```

This code works fine when the user is adding/editing a Sales Order. They are getting the following Exception after they have save the Sales Order, create a Shipment and go to confirm it:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
Stack Trace:
at PX.Objects.SO.SOOrderEntry_Extension.SOLine_UsrMargin_FieldUpdated(PXCache cache, PXFieldUpdatedEventArgs e) in g:\projects\xxx\Automatica\Projects\XXX\WebSite\App_RuntimeCode\SOOrderEntry.cs:line 47
at PX.Data.PXCache.OnFieldUpdated(String name, Object row, Object oldValue, Boolean externalCall)
at PX.Data.PXCache`1.a(TNode A_0, TNode A_1, TNode A_2)
```

This is running on Acumatica Version 6.10.1122

Comment: The error is pretty specific on where it's coming from: SOOrderEntry.cs:line 47, either add whole unmodified SOOrderEntry file to your answer or specify which line of your code is 47.

Comment: I updated the OP with the line number

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the value of your custom field it will be better for you to change your code to something like this

```
SOLineExt rowExt = PXCache<SOLine>.GetExtension<SOLineExt>(salesOrderEntry); 
decimal margin=0;// or set any default value for margin for calculation if rowExt==null
if(rowExt!=null)
{
    margin = rowExt.usrMargin;
}
```

Also I will suggest you to rename `salesOrderEntry` which is the instance of current row to something like `currentRow`, so that your code become more readable.

Comment: Why does this work:

    PXCache<SOLine>

but this doesn't:

    cache.GetValue<SOLineExt.usrMargin>

Comment: @Rob because your code will not work in case if extension is `null`. If you read Training Guide of Acumatica T200,T300 this is the recommended way to work with DAC extensions.